# 64bit integer in JavaScript, from Mysql request

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, integer, 64-bit

I have this number 76561197993482001 (64bit int) stored as a bigint(20) in my database.

But when I try to fetch it using :

```
//node.js
    query('SELECT * FROM table',function(err,rows){
      console.log(rows[0]["id"]);// I get 76561197993482000
      });
```

I get the wrong number. I guess this is because js can't handle 64bit variables.

I know there are libraries for bigint in js but This number is directly stored in the rows variable. So How can I do?

Is there a way to convert it as a text when I send the request?

Comment: Depending on what middleware you're using, most of them have a setting that enables support for big numbers, [the most common middleware](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/) uses the `supportBigNumbers` option for this.

Comment: try to cast the bigint to string in sql query itself

Comment: Thanks! The supportBigNumbers option did the job!

Comment: @adeneo: Please turn this into an answer so we can upvote it properly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what middleware you're using, most of them have a setting that enables support for big numbers, the most common middleware uses the `supportBigNumbers` option for this

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host              : 'example.org',
  user              : 'bob',
  password          : 'secret',
  supportBigNumbers : true
});
```